# How to calculate week ending date in hive using Saturday as week ending date?

Tags: sql, date, hadoop, hive, dayofweek

I had a scenario where I wanted to calculate week ending date (given a date), considering week ends at Saturday. I read some answers but could not find the solution, so I am posting my approach here. Hope it helps somebody like me.

```
select 
TransactionDateTime,
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u') as wkday,
date_add (TransactionDateTime,
case when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u')=7 then 6 
when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u')=1 then 5
when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u')=2 then 4
when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u')=3 then 3
when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u')=4 then 2
when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u')=5 then 1
when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u')=6 then 0
end) as UsageWkEndDt
from TransTable;
```

Comment: Please remove your answer

Comment: You give no example of actual input format, and no example of expected output, e.g. *" given a String '2016-03-03 21:05' that points to a Thursday, I expect a String '2016-03-05' i.e. the next-or-equal Saturday"*

Comment: And you don't give the Hive version -- as of V1.2.0 you have the built-in function `next_day(string start_date, string day_of_week)` cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Comment: Regarding your doubt for expected date format - standard datetime format (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss) or even standard date(yyyy-MM-dd) will be accepted here. If we have some different format we can easily handle that using unix_timestamp method in hive. This approach is good for Hive 1.0.0 as this version is supported in latest EMR release (emr-4.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
TransactionDateTime,
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u') as wkday,
date_add (TransactionDateTime,
case when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u')=7 then 6 
when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u')=1 then 5
when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u')=2 then 4
when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u')=3 then 3
when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u')=4 then 2
when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u')=5 then 1
when from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(TransactionTime),'u')=6 then 0
end) as UsageWkEndDt
from TransTable;
```